# Flex 3.5: workaround for bug where backspace causes browser back action

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Flex 3.5 has this bug where in IE (and some others) where if you push the backspace key in some text boxes, the browser acts like you just pushed its back button. According to [the bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-34047) this is "resolved" because it works in 4.0. But I need a workaround for 3.5. Is there one?

Comment: See my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975736/backspace-issue-in-flex-application-on-ie-8-and-ie-11/29975737#29975737

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it seems that this has nothing to do w/the `<mx:TextInput />` or whatever other people were saying it is. This was all because I was using the `<mx:TabNavigator />`. In any case, getting rid of that tag and replacing it w/a combination of `<mx:TabBar />` and `<mx:ViewStack />` eliminated the problem for me under IE.

Unfortunately, this was a very large undertaking for me, because even though I had only half a dozen `<mx:TabNavigator />`s to fix, the order in which events are thrown is different, so component construction resulted in a lot of components not being created when first accessing tabs and stuff. I found I had to use `<mx:TabBar />`'s `itemClick` event for some things, and then `<mx:ViewStack />`'s `change` for others.